# how to save last read of pdf file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package to read pdf files. Everything is ok but I want to save the last read and when the user enters the next day,  it will lead to the same page as yesterday. How should I try?

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/page-navigation#callbacks.try this document .here pdfpage change listner available .so you keep the last read page from this callback  to the sharedpreference or other storage whenever open the pdf app . you have `jumpto` method .so using this method you can move to that page without any hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SfPdfViewer page navigation supports the PdfPageChangedCallback to notify the page changes.

Page changed callback
The `onPageChanged` callback triggers when the page is changed in the `SfPdfViewer`.

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: SfPdfViewer.network(
    'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
    onPageChanged: (PdfPageChangedDetails details) {
      print(details.newPageNumber);
      print(details.isFirstPage);
    },
  ));
}
```

[syncfusionpdfviewer](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/page-navigation#callbacks)

You can keep the page number from the callback in sharedpreference.After app closed and repopen or your logic you check the page number in the shared preference and `JumptoPage` that page with pagenumber . `_pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(pagenumber)`

**Jumpto page**

```
late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;

@override
void initState() {
  _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PdfViewer'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(5);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: SfPdfViewer.network(
      'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
      controller: _pdfViewerController,
    ),
  );
}
```